# How to get data from LinkedIn?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I have an application where I want to get organizational data from LinkedIn like the name of an organization, address etc. Searching on the web I find out there is Organization Lookup API and there is Organization Search API on LinkedIn, just want to know how can I implement these APIs?

As per the documentation provided by the LinkedIn, I have created my app on the LinkedIn platform and have got the client ID and the Secret Key and have generated the required auto 2.0 access token, now when i try to hit the organization lookup API it gives me 403 error

Comment: Hi Ankur, Welcome to SO! It is always helpful to specify what have you done till now to achieve the results.

Comment: As per the documentation provided by the LinkedIn, I have created my app on the LinkedIn platform and have got the client ID and the Secret Key and have generated the required auto 2.0 access token, now when i try to hit the organization lookup API it gives me 403 error

Answer (score 0):

i do not think you can implement it because for the V2 API of linkedin you need a partnership. you can request a partnership for linkedin for free on their website.
the 403 error is a forbidden error because you do not have the permissions you need.

the V1 API is fully useable for people without a partnership.

> partnering with LinkedIn provides you with additional API functionality & data access, increased call limits & dedicated support. Read more about our various Partner Programs and use cases and see if one is a match for your app. Applications are only accepted when we feel that they're providing value to members, developers and LinkedIn.

**LINK TO PARTNERSHIP PROGRAMS:**
https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

Comment: https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations/{organization ID}
I want to use the following API, is it available in v1?

Comment: unfortunatly not.